# how to set permissions in firebase firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

```
    $path = "firebase_auth.json";

    $config = array(
        "projectId" => "XXXX",
        "keyFile" => json_decode(file_get_contents($path), true)
    );
    $firestore = new FirestoreClient($config);
    $collectionReference = $firestore->collection('Channels');
    $snapshot = $collectionReference->documents().get();
```

Response of this code is

> An uncaught Exception was encountered
>
> Type: Google\Cloud\Core\Exception\ServiceException
>
> Message: { "message": "Missing or insufficient permissions.", "code": 7, "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED", "details": [] }
>
> Filename: /var/www/html/riglynx/vendor/google/cloud/Core/src/GrpcRequestWrapper.php
>
> Line Number: 263

Comment: It looks like you don't have permission to read `Channels`. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started. The simplest (but least locked down) version is in the `ALLOW ALL` box of the second example on that page.

Answer (score 2):

check out [Get started with Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0) documentation. And see [Writing conditions for Cloud Firestore Security Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions?authuser=0) documentation.

> One of the most common security rule patterns is controlling access
>   based on the user's authentication state. For example, your app may
>   want to allow only signed-in users to write data:
>
> ```
> service cloud.firestore {
>   match /databases/{database}/documents {
>     // Allow the user to access documents in the "cities" collection
>     // only if they are authenticated.
>     match /cities/{city} {
>       allow read, write: if request.auth.uid != null;
>     }
>   }
> }
> ```

This should help you get started.

Comment: i need a full access of all document not particular document

Comment: click [ALLOW ALL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started?authuser=0#writing_rules) for the exact code to paste in.

Answer (score 0):

Reason you are getting the error is because you are not allowed to access documents of the collection called Channels.

In order to fix this, you have login to your console firebase.
Navigate to Database > Under firestore database, you have to click on Rules.

Under rules, you can give permission as per your wish.
If you want to give access to al the users then you can simple replace current code with the following code. (Not a good practice and not secure too)

```
service cloud.firestore {
 match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
    allow read, write;
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write : if true;
    }
  }
}
 i set that also

Comment: can you ensure you are using right database? 

if yes, you can test in from Simulator too. You can find simulator in rules tab. You can try with authentication on and off and see the response.

Comment: If simulator is giving the error then you need to re check your rules. Copy and paste above given code and try again.